# casperjs: proper way to display debug information to output

Tags: javascript, scope, casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  logLevel:'debug',
  verbose:true
});

casper.start('http://pcdtattoo.en.alibaba.com/productlist.html',function getItems(){
  var products = this.evaluate(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    var c = $('.app-productsGalleryView li');
    var items = [];
    c.each(function(){
      var product = {};
      product.title = $(this).find('.product-title>a').text().trim();
      product.link = $(this).find('.product-title>a').attr('href');
      product.img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      items.push(product);
    })
    return items;
  })
  this.echo("test:"+ Array.isArray(products));    //works
  products.forEach(function(item,i){
    this.echo('Test:' + i);                      //not working
  })
}
```

I usually use `this.echo` to display debug information to the output. In above code, the first `this.echo` call works and will output `test:true` along with other debug informations. The 2nd one doesn't work and outputs nothing, what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

[It's all about context.](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

In your case `this` refers to the `window.object`  and is probably not what you're expecting. The native `forEach` accepts a second argument (`arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`) which allows you to pass a context.

### Example

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function () {
    console.log(this); //  this refers to window
});

// output
[object DOMWindow]
[object DOMWindow]
[object DOMWindow]


[1,2,3].forEach(function () {
    console.log(this); //  this refers to caspar
}, this);

// output
[object Casper], currently at https://localhost/de/register
[object Casper], currently at https://localhost/de/register
[object Casper], currently at https://localhost/de/register
```

**Hint:** [It's always good to know your API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEac). ;)